# uDeploy where is the location of the audit log

Tags: udeploy

I'm trying to find the audit log in uDeploy but all i can find are the changes.  Can someone point me to where I can find the audit log?  I have looked for an audit tab or a link to generate the audit log but haven't been able to find any information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found to get to the audit logs you need to have enough privileges to see the Settings tab.  So to get to the Audit Logs you go Settings then there is a System section that has the link to the Audit Logs.

Thanks